# Resources that help build intuition about mathematics

Tags: intuition, book-recommendation, visualization

I am looking for any books or resources that help build intuition at a fundamental level about mathematics.

I have a newfound interest in maths, after being away from it for years. Recently I started working on ML and found that I find the mathematics behind it enjoyable.

I like to imagine mathematics visually and am eager if can get any suggestions.

Comment: Given your interest, probability and statistics, algorithms and data structures, and a programming language or two would be good choices and keep you busy for a while.

Comment: I don't know what "ML" is. But the way to build intuition about math is to do math. Try an introductory textbook on Number Theory, or Combinatorics.